# Flink SQL Client connect to non local cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

Is it possible to connect the flink sql client to a remote cluster? I assume the client uses some configuration to determine job manager address, but I don’t see it mentioned in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

You can configure the connection to a remote cluster in the `conf/flink-conf.yaml` file:

```
jobmanager.rpc.address: localhost
jobmanager.rpc.port: 6123
```

Comment: My remote jobmanager is hosted on AWS EKS and a load balancer is also added there, and all I want is to use sql-client from my local to publish jobs there. I tired to paas the exposed url to jobmanager.rpc.address and port but its unkoble to find the host. Can you help me in this?