# Flink 1.12.0 sql client queries hive table

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to do hive query with flink sql client and modify the sql-client-defaults.yaml

1. choose the execution type to `batch` mode as:

   execution:

   ```
   planner: blink

   type: batch
   ```
2. define the hive catalog and set the current-catalog to be `hive`

   catalogs:

   ```
   - name: myhive

     type: hive

     hive-conf-dir: /software/apache-hive-2.3.7-bin/conf/

     default-database: default
   ```

Then I startup sql client with:

`sql-client.sh embedded`

I could see the hive databases and tables.

Then I do following tables;

1. `use testdb;   ---success`
2. `select * from t1 limit 10; ---fail`

The second step fails with following exception:

```
Flink SQL> select * from t1;
2020-12-21 11:33:27,755 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf                         [] - HiveConf of name hive.metastore.local does not exist
2020-12-21 11:33:28,599 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat                     [] - Total input paths to process : 1
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I would ask how to fix the `connection refused` exception

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

After I startup the flink standalone cluster, then the query succeeds. I would ask

1. why should I have to startup the flink standalone cluster, I have thought it is running in the local mode(I have the sql client with sql-client.sh `embedded`)
2. Could I be able to the sql client on yarn cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql client relies on being able to submit a query to a cluster. "Embedded" refers to this architecture,

[image]

where the SQL executor is embedded in the SQL client. But the Flink cluster is still external to the SQL client. See [FLIP-24](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-24+-+SQL+Client) for more on this.

For connecting the SQL client to a non-local cluster, the SQL Client YAML has a deployment section. You can use the regular flink run options there and configure e.g. your YARN session cluster. See also [Flink SQL Client connect to non local cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61652610/2000823).